# How to generate a Log BarLegend for a DensityHistogram

Tags: legending, histograms, logarithmic-scale

I have a Log count histogram:

```
DensityHistogram[myData, 100, {"Log", "Count"}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

But `ChartLegends -> Automatic` generates an incorrect bar legend: it is linear and doesn't match the data. How can I generate the correct bar legend for a log-count density histogram?

The image depicts the linear (top - doesn't have the `{"Log", "Count"}` argument) histogram and the log-count histogram (bottom). They both have the same legend, which is wrong.

[image: DensityHistograms]

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment.

It doesn't seem to happen in V9, so perhaps it's a version bug:

```
SeedRandom[42];
myData = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 1000]; 
DensityHistogram[myData, 10, #, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    ChartLegends -> Automatic] & /@ {{"Log", "Count"}, "Count"} // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, must be. I just ran it in version 10 and the bar legends are incorrect.

Comment: Do you know how to generate the bar legend manually? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a verified BUG in Mathematica 10.1.

Comment: You mean verified by Wolfram Research? If not I would not give this as an answer.

Comment: Yea. I got an email from Wolfram support confirming this was a bug in version 10. It was working in a previous version (9), but there's a problem with it now.